# Why can't I override setOnItemSelectedListener in MDC Navigation bar for Android studio?

Tags: java, android, material3

```
private void SelectedItem() {
    NavigationBarView navigationBarView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    navigationBarView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.item_1:
                    // Handle item_1 selection
                    return true; // Return true if you've handled the selection.
                case R.id.item_2:
                    // Handle item_2 selection
                    return true; // Return true if you've handled the selection.
                default:
                    return false; // Return false for unhandled selections.
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```
new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) -> {

    switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.item_1:
            return true;
        case R.id.item_2:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
});
```

Referring in Java, I tried using both the lambda expression and the overriding method, but no matter what I've tried it doesn't work. Yes, I've tried Kotlin and it works but i want to use java for my project base entirely.
I cannot override the SetOnItemSelectedListener referring to both the methods i've tried.
Can anyone explain how i can either use override method or lambda expression correctly?
It either gives me getItemId()/getId() error or "R.id.item_1" error.

Comment: So your problem isn't the lambda, it is the use of a `switch` statement? Does it work in Java if you use if/else if statements?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Ahh found it, yes its better to initialize the int value, however only override method works and not the lambda expression. Thank you very much